# Existence of open convex set separating a closed, compact convex set and a point

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, compactness, normed-spaces

If $(V, ||\cdot||)$ is a normed vector space and $A \subseteq C$ is compact (and therefore closed since the topology on $V$ induced by $||\cdot||$ is Hausdorff) and convex, and $x \in V \backslash A$, then does there exist an open, convex subset $U$ of $V$ such that $A \subseteq U$ but $x \notin U$?

I'm thinking that there is such a set $U$, if we define $ \varepsilon := \inf_{a \in A} ||a - x||$ (is this infimum necessarily finite?), then does $U := A + \frac 1 2 B(0, \varepsilon)$ satisfy these criteria?

Comment: Yes, it does. Where do you  have difficulty in verifying this?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I think my main struggle is with showing that $\varepsilon$ is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $(V, \|\cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space and $A \subseteq C$ is compact (and therefore closed since the topology on $V$ induced by $\|\cdot\|$ is Hausdorff) and convex, and $x \in V \backslash A$, then does there exist an open, convex subset $U$ of $V$ such that $A \subseteq U$ but $x \notin U$?

Yes. We can even use (one of) the [Hahn-Banach separation theorem(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_separation_theorems) to deduce that there is a hyperplane strictly separating these sets. This means we can even do it with [weakly open sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#The_weak_and_strong_topologies).

> I'm thinking that there is such a set $U$, if we define $ \varepsilon := \inf_{a \in A} \|a - x\|$ (is this infimum necessarily finite?)...

Yes again. Note that $\|a - x\|$ is bounded below by $0$, hence the infimum is not $-\infty$. So long as $A \neq \emptyset$ (which, presumably, it is), the infimum is not $+\infty$. So, the infimum should be finite.

> .. then does $U := A + \frac 1 2 B(0, \varepsilon)$ satisfy these criteria?

Yes once more. Every point in $u \in U$ satisfies $\inf_{a \in A} \|u - a\| < \varepsilon / 2$. Indeed, any $u \in U$ can be expressed in the form $a' + \frac{1}{2}b$, where $b \in B(0, \varepsilon)$. In particular, this means,
$$\frac{\varepsilon}{2} > \frac{1}{2}\|b\| = \|u - a'\| \ge \inf_{a \in A} \|u - a\|.$$
Note that this does not hold for $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer. How do we know $\varepsilon >0$?

Comment: @EhWha Good question. If $\varepsilon = 0$, then there would be some sequence $a_n \in A$ such that $\|x - a_n\| \to 0$. In particular, this means $x \in \overline{A} = A$, since $A$ is compact and hence closed.